# Use PHP variable in Java Script contained within HTML

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to use PHP variable in Java Script, I would like to get the variables of longitude and latitude which is returned from Select statement read from mysql database on the server.

here with my code below and what I have tried:

```
    <?php

...


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Latitude, Longitude FROM mytable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $long = " ". $row["Longitude"]. "<br>";
    $lat = " ". $row["Latitude"]. "<br>";
    $latlong = " ". $row["Longitude"]. " , " . $row["Latitude"]. "<br>";
    echo $long;  //echo's -25.1234
    echo $lat; //echo's 25.1234
    echo $latlong; //echo's -25.1234 ,  25.1234
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?> 

<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Tracker</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>

  <div id="map" style="width: 1200px; height: 750px;"></div>

  <script language="JavaScript"> 

            var locations = [
              ['FirstColumnString<br/> SecondColumnString', -25.038326, 25.038326], //I would like to pass Lat Long from PHP code from above
            ];

        // I've tried
        //  ['FirstColumnString<br/>SecondColumnString', <?php echo $long; ?>, <?php echo $lat; ?>,
        //  ['FirstColumnString<br/>SecondColumnString', <?php echo $latlong ?>,
        //  ['FirstColumnString<br/>SecondColumnString', "<?php echo $long; ?>", <?php echo $lat; ?>,

...

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you tried, and what are the results?

Comment: `'<?php echo $long; ?>'`, you need the single quotes :). PHP will simply output it, to JS this could look like a variable

Comment: you'd need to save the $lats and $longs into an array, then eigther json_encode it to pass it to js, or iterate over it. So the problem is how to get the values from your while-loop to a javascript-readable variable.

Comment: You need to AJAX the lat/long into the locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$long = " ". $row["Longitude"]. "<br>";
$lat = " ". $row["Latitude"]. "<br>";
```

with

```
$long = $row["Longitude"];
$lat = $row["Latitude"];
```

and then

```
var locations = [
    ['FirstColumnString<br/> SecondColumnString', <?php echo $long; ?>, <?php echo $lat; ?>],
];
```

Comment: this will give him only the very last location!

Comment: @Jeff This was to answer to his question on how to echo the variables. Of course, **if** he has more than one row as result, he needs to use an array or echo the locations (javascript) array from inside a php loop to have all the locations,

Comment: @MattCris Yes, technically that's the correct answer. But I assumed the point here is to look and think further, to guide to better overall solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You should save your locations into an array first:

```
<?php

    $locations = Array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $loc = Array("lat" => $row["Latitude"], "long" => $row["Longitude"]);
       $locations[] = $loc;
    }
?>
```

then you can pass it to javascript:

```
<script>
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>;
// check what you've got:
console.log(locations);
</script>
```

you could then access your values like this:

```
var firstLocationLatitude = location[0].lat;
```

*If you need* to have your js-array exactly as you've posted change php to:

```
    $clmString = "FirstColumnString<br/> SecondColumnString";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $loc = Array($clmString,$row["Latitude"],$row["Longitude"]);
       $locations[] = $loc;
    }
```